# Scipy Welch's gives different first element

Tags: fourier-transform, python, spectrogram, software-implementation, scipy

I've re-implemented Welch's method and want to compare it to `scipy.signal.welch`. However, the first two and last elements of the resulting array are different.

My Welchs function (not optimized and without taper, as this is not the issue here)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

def welchs(signal, nperseg=512, noverlap=0):
    taper = np.ones(nperseg) # assume boxcar taper for simplicity
    scale = 1.0 / (1 * (taper*taper ).sum()/2)
    siglen = signal.shape[-1]
    step = nperseg - noverlap
    fft_segments = []
    for i in range(0, siglen, step):
        if i+nperseg>siglen: 
            print(i+nperseg, '>', siglen)
            break 
        segment = signal[i:i+nperseg]
        w = np.fft.rfft(segment)
        fft_segments.append(np.abs(w)**2)
    fft_segments = np.array(fft_segments)
    fft_mean = np.mean(fft_segments, 0)
    return fft_mean * scale
```

testing:

```
signal = np.sin(np.linspace(0,512, 1024))

w1 = welchs(signal, nperseg=512, noverlap=0)
_,w2 = scipy.signal.welch(signal, nperseg=512, noverlap=0, detrend=False, window='boxcar')
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(w1,w2) # -> 0.7% mismatch, 2 elements
```

All elements of `w1` and `w2` are the same except the first and the last.

Can anyone explain to me what my implementation might be missing?

Comment: Is there a factor of $2$ (or $1/2$, respectively) between `w1` and `w2`?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case, but only for the first elements